# Get Average of rating using lrlaravel eloquent for users

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, laravel

I am getting all user. Each user having multiple rating. I have to find out average of each user rating. Here is my code as below:

```
$specializationObjModal = DoctorsModal::with('user')->with('doctorSpecialization')->get();
      

      $data = array();
            foreach($specializationObjModal as $dataObj)
            {
                $data[]['user_id'] = $dataObj->user_id;
            }
            $ids = $data;
            $doctor_rating = UserRatings::select('rating','rated_for_user_id')
            ->whereIn('rated_for_user_id', $ids)
            ->where('rating', '<>', '')
            ->get();
           
            $sum = 0;
            $count = 0;
            foreach( $doctor_rating as $rating){
             
                if($rating->rated_for_user_id){
                 
                    $count++;
                    $sum += $rating->rating;
                }
            }
    
           return $avg = $sum / $count;
```

According to my code I am getting average of all user rating. But I want average of each user Rating according to their Id's because every user having multiple rating and I have to calculate each user rating . Please tell me where I am Wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you want `avg_rating` on user collection so

in you `User.php`

```php
protected $appends = ['avg_rating'];

public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
{
    return UserRatings::where('rated_for_user_id', $this->id)
        ->avg('rating');
}
```

then in your this collection user object will have new key `avg_rating`

```php
$specializationObjModal = DoctorsModal::with('user')->with('doctorSpecialization')->get();
```

ref link

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'e_health.user_ratings.rating' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select avg(rating) as avg_rating, `rating`, `rated_for_user_id` from `user_ratings` where `rated_for_user_id` in (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 154, 155) and `rating` <>  and "

Comment: @jandialnidhi check now

Comment: But now it calculated empty row value also

Comment: I want only those rows average which are not empty

Comment: your getting user with avg ? right now you can merge with any collection whenever you need if you show me which collection you need i can help you

Comment: yes need to show with this.... $specializationObjModal = DoctorsModal::with('user')->with('doctorSpecialization')->get();

Comment: @jandialnidhi check now i think i understand correctly what you need ?